# Thread32First returning bogus thread id

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

`Thread32First` returns true so I know the function isn't failing. However, it keeps returning the same value for the `th32ThreadID` data member of `THREADENTRY32`, 0. Doesn't matter what process I try it on, it continues to be the same thread id: 0.

Here's my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL EnableDebugPriv(HANDLE proc);

int main()
{
    HANDLE hSnapshot;

    HANDLE hThread;

    THREADENTRY32 thread32;

    DWORD dwPid     = 15404;

    EnableDebugPriv(OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwPid));

    hSnapshot       = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, dwPid);

    if(hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Error getting snapshot: %lu\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    thread32.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);

    if(!Thread32First(hSnapshot, &thread32))
    {
        printf("Error thread32first\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Thread Id: %lu\n", thread32.th32ThreadID);

    hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, thread32.th32ThreadID);

    if(hThread == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error getting handle: %lu\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

BOOL EnableDebugPriv(HANDLE proc)
{
        HANDLE hToken;
        LUID sedebugnameValue;
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;
        // pass our opened process handle
        OpenProcessToken(proc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);
        LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &sedebugnameValue);
        tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        tkp.Privileges[0].Luid = sedebugnameValue;
        tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
        if(AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, sizeof tkp, NULL, NULL))
        {
        CloseHandle(hToken);
        return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,"Bro, you gotta be an admin to set privs like this", "Shit", MB_OK);
            CloseHandle(hToken);
            return FALSE;
        }


}
```

Note: I am aware that using a static process ID like I am could cause problems. However, I make sure the process is still running with the same process ID. That's not the problem.

Comment: Why aren't you reading documentation? [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489.aspx) returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` on error. Full sample code available at [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable I've used `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` multiple times and I incorrectly remembered the error return value being `NULL`. I corrected it, ran my program again and it didn't return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Comment: For some reason the first 3 threads id's are 0 in all processes I use it on then it goes to 12 and higher after that. Is it supposed to be that way?

Comment: at first you got `Includes all threads in the system in the snapshot` so first entry will be not related to your process. and second your `EnableDebugPriv` completely wrong

Comment: Why don't you read [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489.aspx)? `TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD` *"[i]ncludes all threads in the system in the snapshot. [...] To identify the threads that belong to a specific process, compare its process identifier to the th32OwnerProcessID member of the THREADENTRY32 structure when enumerating the threads."*

Comment: you need enumerate entries and compare `thread32.th32OwnerProcessID == dwPid`. also about `EnableDebugPriv` - main you need do this with yourself process token. at second return of `AdjustTokenPrivileges` true/false not relevant - it return true even if fail. you need call `GetLastError` and compare it to 0. and you can not call `LookupPrivilegeValue` but use well know constant - `#define SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE                  (20L)`